# Compensation for cancelled flight for multiple passengers

Tags: air-travel, eu, compensation, passenger-rights, klm

My flight with KLM was cancelled and I rebooked to a flight that makes me eligible for compensation. I was travelling with my family. Does anyone know if I should make individual compensation claims for each passenger or one claim is enough? On the KLM form there was no place to provide the details of other passengers, but we all travelled under one PNR.

Comment: Does the KLM form provide a space to specify what you're claiming?  If so, list the passengers there and specify the corresponding amount.  The one claim I've pursued was for two travelers on a single PNR; we did not submit separate claims, and the claim was successful (but it was with a different airline).  There's no point in making more paperwork for yourself if the airline doesn't require it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, you need to make one claim per passenger.

While you are part of the same family, there are other situations when a group of people travel on the same booking (e.g. work colleagues) and each is entitled to their own compensation, so it makes sense to apply separately.

Comment: When I was eligible for compensation from Lufthansa because of a cancelled flight, I submitted a single claim for my wife and myself.  The claim was eventually paid after some foot dragging, but there was never any suggestion that there should have been two separate claims.  Even if the regulation doesn't require airlines to handle group claims, the airline might nonetheless accept one.